# Find out the min, max, total of an input text file and write it into a new output text file?

Tags: java, file, printwriter

```
package file_handling;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WriteToFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {

      int currentNumber, sum = 0, numberCount=0;
      FileReader infile; 

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      File file2 = new File("D:/test1.txt");
      input = new Scanner(file2);
        int min;
        int max;
      while (input.hasNextInt()){
        currentNumber = input.nextInt();
        sum+=currentNumber;

        numberCount++;
        if(currentNumber < min) {
            min= currentNumber;
        }
        if(currentNumber > max) {
            max = currentNumber; 
        }
      }

      System.out.println("Min: " + min);

      System.out.println("Max: " + max);

      System.out.println("Total: " + sum);

    File file1 = new File("D:/test.txt");
    try {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file1);
        output.write(max, min, sum);
        output.close(); //don't forget this method 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

}
```

input.txt:

```
9.22

11.55

-2.21

16.95

22.11

-5.11
```

Based on the content of input.txt, I'm trying to write a program to find out the maximum number, the minimum number and the total of those numbers and write the results into a file named output.txt file.

output.txt:

```
Min:

Max:

Total:
```

I have to use the Scanner class to read from the file and the PrintWriter class to write out to the file.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, could someone help me please?

I get this error at line 44: `output.write(max, min, sum);`
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method write(char[], int, int) in the type PrintWriter is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int)

> at file_handling.WriteToFile.main(WriteToFile.java:44)

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: There is no method of `PrintWriter` that takes in `(int, int, int)`. Also are the values of min, max and sum correct? It looks like your while loop is being skipped.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues :

1. Your code won't compile as there is no method of `PrintWriter`
   that takes in `(int, int, int)`. You can use the method
   `write(String s)` to achieve the same.

   ```
   output.write(String.valueOf("Min: " + min + "\n\nMax: " + max + "\n\nTotal : " + sum));
   ```
2. The file is read as a sequence of bytes, so you'll need to use
   `input.hasNextLine()` to read each line. With your current code, your while loop is not executed. Next you will need to
   convert each *String* to *Double*. So your while-loop needs to
   tweaked to as below :

   ```
   while (input.hasNextLine()) {
       String currLine = input.nextLine(); 

       // check for empty spaces
       if (currLine != null && currLine.trim().length() > 0) {
           currentNumber = Double.parseDouble(currLine); 

           // same from here
           sum += currentNumber;
           numberCount++;
           if (currentNumber < min) {
               min = currentNumber;
           }
           if (currentNumber > max) {
               max = currentNumber;
           }       
       }
   }
   ```
3. You cant use int to store double values. So declare all your int to
   double. (Also not sure why you are using *numberCount*, it can be removed.)

   ```
   double currentNumber, sum = 0, numberCount = 0, min = 0, max = 0;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use printf instead of write:

```
output.printf("Max:  %d\n", max);
output.printf("Min:  %d\n", min);
output.printf("Total:  %d\n", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java 8 or Java 9 you could write way shorter and simpler code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DoubleSummaryStatistics statistics = Files
      .lines(new File("./test1.txt").toPath())
      .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
      .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
      .summaryStatistics();

    double min = statistics.getMin();
    System.out.println("Min: " + min);
    double max = statistics.getMax();
    System.out.println("Max: " + max);
    double sum = statistics.getSum();
    System.out.println("Total: " + sum);

    Files.write(new File("./test2.txt").toPath(), List.of(Double.toString(min), Double.toString(max), Double.toString(sum)));
  }
```

The [nio-API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) defines classes and methods to works with files which also handles the [closing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) of files (resources).

The [Stream-API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) has classes and methods to process elements. To compute the sum, max and min values for a stream of doubles (`DoubleStream`) we can use the method `DoubleStream.summaryStatistics()`.

If you cannot use Java 9 use `Arrays.asList()` instead of `List.of()`